# Confidence interval for sum of random variables

Tags: summation, random-variables, means, confidence-interval

Suppose I have realizations $x_1, ..., x_n$ for random variable $X$ and I have realizations $y_1, ... , y_m$ for random variable $Y$. $n<<m$ are small numbers.

Let $ Z = a*X + b*Y $, where $a,b$ constants.  How can I derive a confidence interval for the mean $\mu_Z$?

Can I simply use bootstrapping? That is, suppose $F_n$ and $H_m$ are the empirical distribution functions obtained from the two sets of realizations. I could, for example, generate many bootstrap samples $z_i^* = x_i^* + y_i^*$, $i = 1, ...$ , compute the empirical distribution of (studentized) means and then the confidence interval.

Is this a reasonable procedure or am I making a conceptual mistake somewhere? By the way, this question is motivated by a real application. For that I am actually interested in a sum of random variables with many terms, all of which have a different number of observations.

Comment: Why not just use the student-t CI for the mean of $Z$ with $k=\min\{n,m\}$ samples?

Comment: I thought of that, but it's possible that n << m. Using this approach might lead to a rather wide confidence interval- also depending on coefficients a and b (see edit).